# Как поменять цикл while на for?

Tags: c++

я стараюсь не использовать цикл `while`, потому что он мне не нравиться.
Но мне нужно вызвать функцию `ReceiveAndPrint` и проверить ее, не равна ли она `0`, после этого завершить цикл.

Через `while` это делается так.

```
while (ReceiveAndPrint(ConnSocket, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer)) != 0);
```

Вопрос как тоже самое делать через цикл `for`

Comment: Вероятно, следовало бы задать вопрос "Как избавиться от необоснованной неприязни к циклу while?"...

Comment: @aa_talanin Обосновать достаточно легко - while без тела.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(;;)
{
    if(0 != ReceiveAndPrint(ConnSocket, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer)))
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: А вот это я не подумал что так можно :)

Comment: Что то не так, он почему то срабатывает второй раз, надо наверно по другому сделать типа проверки.

Comment: срабатывает break только со второго раза, есть другой вариант?

Comment: Сделал немного по другому, вначале проверку а потом вызов, код стал немного больше но зато понятней.

Answer (score 3):

Цикл

```
while (условие)
  ...
```

полностью эквивалентен циклу

```
for (; условие; )
  ...
```

поэтому в вашем случае формальная замена будет выглядеть просто как

```
for (; ReceiveAndPrint(ConnSocket, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer)) != 0; );
```

В чем смысл такой замены и зачем она вам понадобилась, правда, не ясно.

Comment: Человек же написал: ему не **нравиться** цикл `while` хД